# PowerBI Server: Refresh failed due to gateway configuration issues

Tags: database, powerbi, connectivity

I am using Azure Database for MySQL with the following configuration as the data source on a PowerBI report

Firewall Rules: Allow access to Azure services
SSL Settings: Enforce SSL connection is set to disabled
PowerBI Desktop is able to connect to the database.

I then publish the report. Go to app.powerbi.com/home and refresh the dataset.

I get the error Refresh failed due to gateway configuration issues

I do not have any gateways configured given that the database is on Azure

Any tips/guidance would be appreciated.

**Some details from the error message and connection to db**

Refresh failed due to gateway configuration issues.

This dataset requires a properly configured gateway in order to refresh.

If you're using personal mode, please make sure your gateway is online.

If you're using enterprise mode, please make sure you've added the following data sources in the Gateway Management PortalMySql { server : "XYZ.mysql.database.azure.com" , database : "SOMEDB" }

Please try again later or contact support.

Comment: You created the gateway in the website? If somebody else did you might not be in the Users list.